# Problem with iteration over PolynomialFeatures

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to code a for loop that iterates over the degrees of the polynomial and returns the r2 score. Below is my code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

X_data=data[["Horsepower", "Peakrpm","Enginesize","Wheelbase","Compressionratio"]]
y_data = log_data

s = StandardScaler()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_data, y_data,test_size=0.3,random_state=42)
X_train = s.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = s.transform(X_test)

print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
for i in range(3):
    poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=i,include_bias=False, interaction_only=False)
     
    X_train=pd.DataFrame(poly.fit_transform(X_train),
    columns=poly.get_feature_names(input_features=data.columns))
    lr_poly=LinearRegression().fit(X_train,y_train)
    print(lr_poly.score(X_train,y_train))
```

and i am getting this error

```
could not broadcast input array from shape (143,5) into shape (143,0)
```

Should i do a reshape somewhere to `X_train`?

I understand that `X_train` gets different shape over the iterations because of the degree polynomial, but since it only gets more columns, why is this error keeps popping up?

Comment: Where exactly? Please update your post with the full error trace - see how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You keep overriding `X_train` in the loop,  so the input to the `PolynomialFeatures` keeps growing, but you specify `data.columns` inside the `get_feature_names` method, which stays fixed.  That doesn't quite fit the error message, but it certainly should cause a problem.